# line breaks after Java annotations in Scala code

Tags: java, scala, annotations

I have a code that compiles successfully:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path

trait DescriptionHandler extends ServiceAwareHandler {
  @Path("/descriptions")
  def getDescriptionsRoute: Route = ...
}
```

and it would not compile if I add a line break after Path annotation like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path

trait DescriptionHandler extends ServiceAwareHandler {
  @Path("/descriptions")

  def getDescriptionsRoute: Route = ...
}
```

In IntelliJ IDEA it look like javax.ws.rs.Path is absent in class path.
Compiler telling me this:

```
Error:(19, 1) expected start of definition
  def getDescriptionsRoute: Route =
```

What's the problem with line breaks between Java annotations and Scala methods / fields? I tried to google the issue but didn't found anything useful.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want whitespace between an annotation and the method it should belong to?

Comment: actually, it shouldn't be) I just occasionally put an empty line between annotation and method and it didn't compile! so, now I want to understand why...

Comment: seems like Martin Odersky (the creator of Scala) says "Annotations in front of definitions still can have newlines." in https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-688 perhaps this is a bug worth reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Scala Spec/Lexical syntax/1.2 Newline characters](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#newline-characters) there is an explicit statement about this case:

> A single new line token is accepted
>
> - ...
> - after an annotation.

And when there is an empty line:

> if two tokens are separated by at least one completely blank line (i.e a line which contains no printable characters), then two nl tokens are inserted.

Thus blank lines are not accepted between annotation and definition.

Comment: indeed! but why it is _{Annotation [nl]} {Modifier} Def_ and _{Annotation [nl]} {Modifier} Dcl_ instead of _{Annotation {nl}} {Modifier} Def_ ?